# How do I set a secret in a Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Is there a way to set a secret's value and expiration date from with a Logic App?

I don't see the option listed (I scrolled thru the list to ensure that I wasn't missing it):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is as you suspected, you can not update a secret using the out of the box key vault connector available with Logic Apps. You however can do it using the Keyvault REST reference [Update Secret- REST reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/updatesecret/updatesecret)

I personally write an azure function to perform various key vault operations as I find there are some operations lacking in the out of the box connector in logic app

Comment: If I wanted to change the secret's value and expiration date, then the body would need to be `{
"attributes":{
  "exp": "2020-05-30T12:00:00.0000000Z"
},
"value": "BEARER xxx"
}`

Comment: By 'azure function', do you mean a `Function App`?

Comment: Yes that is correct, create Azure function app with multiple function which I require through out the project. The advantage of doing so is that I can reuse the same functions in multiple places.

Comment: Can they be used with a `Logic App`?

Comment: Yes, just create an azure function with http trigger and call it inside the logic app using http action